# How to have an azure function triggered by cosmosdb and call another http fuction

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a requirement to listen to changes in azure cosmos db, then make a POST call to another api based on the information I received.

I added this function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "validAppsTrigger2_ConnectionString",
      "databaseName": "dev",
      "collectionName": "validApps",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "name": "response",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "http"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my index.js

```
module.exports = function (context, input) {
    context.log('Document Id: ', input[0].id);
    // should I call http manually here?
    context.done();
};
```

but I am not sure how should I call another azure http function from there,

- Do I need an `out` binding at all?
- Should I just make a regular http call in the above function?

Comment: just do a http request to the other function endpoint

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio does it mean I don't need `out` binding, correct?

Comment: Correct, just a regular http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need an out binding at all?

No, HTTP output binding requires an HTTP trigger. You are using Cosmos trigger, so this can't be done.Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output.

> Use the HTTP output binding to respond to the HTTP request sender.
> This binding requires an HTTP trigger and allows you to customize the
> response associated with the trigger's request.

> Should I just make a regular http call in the above function?

Yes, you can just do a regular http call in you function as @Thiago Custodio said.